# Хранение данных для списка SelectList или DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, c#

Впрочем список не большой, 80 строк - субъекты РФ.

- Вариант 1: Без труда могу сохранить в БД. (Но это так сказать лишний запрос).
- Вариант 2: Создать функцию возвращающую полный список (Динамическое создание списка).
- Вариант 3: Напрямую в html разметке (Как то неуклюже).

Вроде мелочусь, но нужна помощь в принятии решения или Ваш вариант. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так: Реализовал динамическое заполнение списка, отрендерил страницу, скопировал html код со списком, создал отдельный partial с регионами.

Теперь выглядит так: `@Html.Partial("regions");`

Думаю, это оптимальное решение для хранения выпадающего списка. А то слегка смущает создание 83 экземпляров selectlistitem только для одного элемента страницы когда ещё и других достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 3** я бы отмёл сразу (хардкод)

**Вариант 1** - интересен если:

- a. Список часто меняеться
- б. Нужна
     будет локализация.

**Вариант 2** - лучше всего его объединить с первым или реализовать без хардкода (с подключаемыми источниками данными - xml или из бд и т.д.)

Я бы выбрал **вариант 2** и внутри его уже бы игрался.